# Is it me or there's a bug in PHP DateTime?

Tags: php, exception, datetime

I've just encountered on a problem I never though would exist.
I have a form that submits dates in the following format `04/28/2013 11:00`. On the user front-end I'm using `jquery datetimepicker` and on the backend I have php to process the form.

Doing some testing I found out that `DateTime` in php does not throw an exception when the time is broken. For example this `04/28/2013 11:00123123` would not trigger an exception - instead `DateTime` returns `now` time. In my case the date is not related to `now` - it's a specific date & time in the future.

In my opinion `DateTime` should return an exception rather than `now` time. Is it me, or this is a bug?

Edit: 
I'm using php 5.3.23

Comment: Have you attempted to [retrieve the errors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.getlasterrors.php)?

Comment: I assume you are referring to the `strtotime` function?  Can you show some code?  Also, it's not a good idea to parse ambiguous date formats. See the third box under "Notes" in [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

Comment: I'm simply using `DateTime` http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php and passing the string from the input directly. @DavidThomas yes, but unfortunately there are no errors.

Comment: @tftd: Upgrade to a newer (>= 5.3) PHP version. You are still using 5.2.x, there is plenty of choice regarding what to upgrade to.

Comment: I'm already using >= 5.3 - my current version is 5.3.23. Can't upgrade to >= 5.4 due to project requirements :)

Comment: @tftd: If you are on 5.3 and it doesn't throw then you found a bug in PHP (or at the very least a documentation bug). Are you 700% sure?

Comment: I'm 1000000% sure, I installed it a couple of weeks ago and `phpinfo` returns that version as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this as an answer as the comments wouldn't fit for it.

```
<?php

new DateTime('04/28/2013 11:00123123');
```

I'm getting:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (04/28/2013 11:00123123) at position 16 (1): Double time specification' in ...

Exception: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (04/28/2013 11:00123123) at position 16 (1): Double time specification in ...
Call Stack:
    0.0001     635184   1. {main}() 
    0.0001     636048   2. DateTime->__construct()
```

I'm using PHP5.3.10. And you?

Comment: "On my machine running 5.3.10, `new DateTime('04/28/2013 11:00123123')` does throw an exception. Please show us the code." <--- fits comfortably in a comment.

Comment: However, will delete the answer after the problem has been resolved. Just wanted to have enough space for the error messages. But you confirm to the answer itself, you're getting an exception too?

Comment: Sure. It's also documented: 5.2.0 <= PHP < 5.3.0 emits error, PHP >= 5.3.0 throws.

Comment: Okey, it appears it's related to the current project I'm working on. I've tried this on another machine and it indeed throws an exception. I'll have to investigate the code a bit more as it's not my project and I just started working with it.